# Can't understand why input string was not in a correct format when instanciating my object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, format

I have a simple form, with three fields, I click on submit I receive the data in the controller, I try to instanciate an object with this data, to add it to my data base via a Repository, But when I click on submit I get an error that you are going to see in the end

So this my controller method : ( I added the int.TryParse method based on an answer here hoping that it is my problem fixing but no )

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult insertBook(string bookName, string bookPrice, string categoryId)
    {
        Category category = _categoryRepository.getCategoryById(Int32.Parse(categoryId));

        int val = 0;
        bool result = int.TryParse(categoryId, out val);

        Book book = result ? new Book(
            10,
            bookName,
            Double.Parse(bookPrice),
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyQzE.png?s=128&g=1&g&s=32",
            val
        ) : new Book(
            10,
            bookName,
            Double.Parse(bookPrice),
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyQzE.png?s=128&g=1&g&s=32",
            3 // default category is with id 3
        );

        _bookRepository.insertBook(book);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Here is my entity Book ( a constructor added ) :

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public double BookPrice { get; set; }
    public string BookImageUrl { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public Book(int bookId, string bookName, double bookPrice, string bookImageUrl, int categoryId){
        BookId = bookId;
        BookName = bookName;
        BookPrice = bookPrice;
        BookImageUrl = bookImageUrl;
        CategoryId = categoryId;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get :

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

When I check for example my data gotten from the form, I see it is in the correct format, I mean that I was expecting ( so Int32.parse should be fine here ), and ***WHY BOOK IS NULL ?***

[image]

Any ideas ?

**Any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Does this occur on the `int.Parse` or on the `double.Parse` call? If it is the latter, it might be an issue with the decimal separator of the current culture. Try `double.Parse(bookPrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format exception is most probable due to `Double.Parse(bookPrice)`. Try to use invariant culture, like this:

```
Convert.ToDouble(bookPrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Just to make sure, you can also use this:

```
double parsedBookPrice;
var isValidDouble = Double.TryParse(bookPrice, out parsedBookPrice);
```

If `isValidDouble` is false, then the `45.00` format, is most probable invalid for the culture of your server.

Comment: Yes, isValidDouble is false, Thanks for detecting that for me, But I still don't get why !

Comment: Try with `45,00`

Comment: I already did that, Thanks, even though I will have a problem later, because I have two apps consuming the same db, But Thanks! that was my problem :D

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers

Comment: @TaouBen: just use `Convert.ToDouble(bookPrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` as Athanasios wrote. This independently of the current culture uses the '.' separator.

Comment: Yes Klaus, I got that, Thanks so much

Comment: Athenasios Yup I already did, you both were helpful